# can we call visualforce page from lighting web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

is there any way to open a visual force page from lighting web component. I have already tried this thing, but that is not working for me.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
            type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: '/apex/Vf page name '    
            }
        });
```

Comment: no this not working for me

Comment: Did you try the first answer, which is NOT what you cite in your question?